# RDP Can't connect - Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, rdp

I'm running two 2008 servers, both of them are Terminal Servers. I Will call them TS1 and TS2. TS1 is the licensing server. Both of them have RDP version 6.1.7600. I Can connect to TS1 from every client, but I can't connect to TS2 from older clients.. (eg; Server 2003, RDP5.2). They both have the same configuration.

I've updated the RDP on the server 2003 to version 6.0 and it's working now, but updating the RDP clients on all the older computers is just to much work.

Why can the older clients RDP to TS1, but not TS2? It's a mysterie for me...

Comment: "updating the RDP clients on all the older computers is just to much work." - Yes. Being a sysadmin sometimes requires work.

Comment: They are using Thin clients (HP Compaq t5510). The latest firmware is installed. This firmware includes RDP 5.2, so updating to 6.x is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did found a new firmware for our Thin Clients (With RDP 6 included) and ended up installing it on each of them.

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the Remote Services Host Configuration on TS2.

Inside the RDP-TCP properties uncheck the box shown in this pic (Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication):

[image]

Then restart Terminal Services.

Comment: Thank you, but this option is already unchecked.

Comment: I've also tested this fix: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

This resolves the problem, and I can connect ONCE. Afther connecting once, the problem comes back.